# Automatic cleanup for tmp/_WL_User in weblogic

Tags: weblogic

We have weblogic 10.3.6.0 installed on windows server. We have stagging deployments enabled.Deployment process consists of undeployment for the old application and deployment for the new application vie python script. Each deployment consists of several .war files.

All .war files are versioned, ex:
application-a-123.war
applicatiom-b-222.war

The problem is that following directory is not cleaned after deployment:
C:\oracle\middleware\user_projects\domains\myApp\servers\SERVER-xy\tmp_WL_user
As the result there are many directories left from older deployments.These directories take to much disk space on server.

Is there a possibility to force weblogic to delete non-used folders in this directory? Or maybe modify deployment process, so older folders will be deleted after deployment?